# How to switch the user tenant id in Grails Multi Tenant Single DB plugin without relogin

Tags: grails, multi-tenant

**Use Case** : A single user with “single user name” should be able to use data available in different tenant without relogin.

**Expected Flow :**

1. User “A” login into tenant 1
2. He done some activity and able to access all tenant 1 data
3. He clicks on the “switch tenant” link and after that he should be able to access all data related to Tenant 2

**Environment :**

1. Grails v2.1
2. spring-security-core v1.2.7.3
3. multi-tenant-single-db v0.8.3

I am using following auto generated class

1. SpringSecurityTenantRepository
2. SpringSecurityTenantResolver

I used following code in controller but it did not work.

```
def switchedTenentId = params.switchedTenentId
if(switchedTenentId != null && !"".equals(switchedTenentId))
   {
     def currUser = springSecurityService.currentUser
     springSecurityService.currentUser.userTenantId = new Long(switchedTenentId)
   }
```

I googled but did not find any solution. I like to know the logic, solution or any sample code.

Thanks

Comment: hi sanjay,can you ping me your mail id..i am facing similar issue

Comment: not able to find your Email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I did:

```
User u = User.get(springSecurityService.currentUser.id)
u.userTenantId = params.switchedTenentId.toInteger()
u.save flush: true
springSecurityService.reauthenticate u.username
```

It worked like a charm.